# No se muestran más contenedores de texto

Tags: html, jquery, css, web, slider

intento añadir más `<p>` al `. timeline-slide__content`  pero no aparecen.

Reviso la altura de los elementos pero es como si algo la bloqueara: les asigno más altura y el el inspector aparecen con esa altura (por ejemeplo le asigno una altura de 600px y me sale " 320px x 600px"), pero siguen estando a la misma altura de antes.

El caso, es que no se muestran mas contenedores de texto.

```js
$(function(){
   $('.timeline-nav').slick({
      slidesToShow: 12,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      asNavFor: '.timeline-slider',
      centerMode: false,
      focusOnSelect: true,
       mobileFirst: true,
      arrows: false,
      infinite:true,
       responsive: [
           {
          breakpoint: 768,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 8,
           }
          },
         {
          breakpoint: 0,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 2,
          }
        }
     ]
  });
  
   $('.timeline-slider').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: false,
      asNavFor: '.timeline-nav',     
      centerMode: true,     
      cssEase: 'ease',
       edgeFriction: 0.5,
       mobileFirst: true,
       speed: 500,
       responsive: [
         {
          breakpoint: 0,
          settings: {
              centerMode: false
          }
        },
           {
          breakpoint: 768,
          settings: {
              centerMode: true
          }
        }
     ]
  });
 
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #003471;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.title {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.timeline {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.timeline-nav__item {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: transparent;
  color: #afc9f6;
  margin: 15px 25px !important;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-weight: 400;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.timeline-nav__item::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #afc9f6;
  transition: .2s;
}
.timeline-nav__item.slick-current {
  color: #ff9900;
  opacity: 1;
}
.timeline-nav__item.slick-current::before {
  background-color: #ff9900;
}
.timeline-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 580px;
  margin: 60px auto;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .timeline-wrapper {
    height: 1000px;
    max-height: 900px;
  }
}
.timeline-slider {
  height: 100%;
}
.timeline .slick-list {
  height: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 1080px) {
  .timeline .slick-list {
    padding: 0 180px !important;
  }
}
.timeline .slick-track {
  height: 100%;
}
.timeline-slide {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  outline: none;
  background-size: auto 400px, cover;
  background-position: top;
  margin: 0 24px;
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.timeline-slide:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 52, 113, 0.8);
  z-index: 2;
}
.timeline-slide__content {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 220px;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 80%;
  max-height: 800px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
          transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
  padding: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .timeline-slide__content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.timeline-year {
  z-index: 5;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ff9900;
  padding: 15px 26px;
  transition: opacity 1.2s;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.timeline-title {
  color: #ff9900;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.timeline-text {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #666666;
}
.timeline .slick-current:after {
  background-color: rgba(0, 52, 113, 0);
}
.timeline .slick-current .timeline-year {
  opacity: 1;
}
.timeline .slick-current .timeline-slide__content {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>PS Group Timeline 2</title>
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700,800'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>

  
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="title">Our Milestones</h1>
  <div class="timeline">
    <div class="timeline-nav">
      <div class="timeline-nav__item">1985</div>
      <div class="timeline-nav__item">1988</div>
      <div class="timeline-nav__item">1998</div>
      <div class="timeline-nav__item">2006</div>
      <div class="timeline-nav__item">2008</div>
      <div class="timeline-nav__item">2010</div>
      <div class="timeline-nav__item">2012</div>
      <div class="timeline-nav__item">2013</div>
      <div class="timeline-nav__item">2015</div>
      <div class="timeline-nav__item">2016</div>
      <div class="timeline-nav__item">2017</div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-wrapper">
      <div class="timeline-slider">
        <div class="timeline-slide" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1920/600?image=11;" data-year="1985">      <span class="timeline-year">X A.C - V D.C</span>
          <div class="timeline-slide__content">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Clasicismo</h4>
            <p class="timeline-text">Producción literaria griega y romana correspondiente a los siglos que van desde el x a de c hasta el v d de cristo</p>
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Contexto</h4>
            <p class="timeline-text">El hombre de la época basa su vida en las divinidades es decir en los dioses</p>
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Caracteristicas y representantes</h4>
            <p class="timeline-text">Búsqueda constante de la belleza</p>
            <p class="timeline-text">Aspiración a conseguir siempre lo mejor</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-slide" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1920/600?image=12;" data-year="1988">      <span class="timeline-year">1988</span>
          <div class="timeline-slide__content">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Our first project</h4>
            <p class="timeline-text">First project for the leading film actress Jamuna Barua, wife of Pramathesh Barua the legendary actor, director, and screenwriter</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-slide" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1920/600?image=13;" data-year="1998">      <span class="timeline-year">1998</span>
          <div class="timeline-slide__content">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Our nice super title</h4>
            <p class="timeline-text">Lorem ipsum dolor site amet, consectetur adipscing elit, sed do eisumod tempor incididut ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad mimim venjam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-slide" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1920/600?image=13;" data-year="2006">      <span class="timeline-year">2006</span>
          <div class="timeline-slide__content">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Our nice super title</h4>
            <p class="timeline-text">Lorem ipsum dolor site amet, consectetur adipscing elit, sed do eisumod tempor incididut ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad mimim venjam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-slide" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1920/600?image=13;" data-year="2008">      <span class="timeline-year">2008</span>
          <div class="timeline-slide__content">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Our nice super title</h4>
            <p class="timeline-text">Lorem ipsum dolor site amet, consectetur adipscing elit, sed do eisumod tempor incididut ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad mimim venjam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-slide" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1920/600?image=13;" data-year="2010">      <span class="timeline-year">2010</span>
          <div class="timeline-slide__content">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Our nice super title</h4>
            <p class="timeline-text">Lorem ipsum dolor site amet, consectetur adipscing elit, sed do eisumod tempor incididut ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad mimim venjam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-slide" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1920/600?image=13;" data-year="2012">      <span class="timeline-year">2012</span>
          <div class="timeline-slide__content">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Our nice super title</h4>
            <p class="timeline-text">Lorem ipsum dolor site amet, consectetur adipscing elit, sed do eisumod tempor incididut ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad mimim venjam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-slide" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1920/600?image=13;" data-year="2013">      <span class="timeline-year">2013</span>
          <div class="timeline-slide__content">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Our nice super title</h4>
            <p class="timeline-text">Lorem ipsum dolor site amet, consectetur adipscing elit, sed do eisumod tempor incididut ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad mimim venjam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-slide" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1920/600?image=13;" data-year="2015">      <span class="timeline-year">2015</span>
          <div class="timeline-slide__content">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Our nice super title</h4>
            <p class="timeline-text">Lorem ipsum dolor site amet, consectetur adipscing elit, sed do eisumod tempor incididut ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad mimim venjam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-slide" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1920/600?image=13;" data-year="2016">      <span class="timeline-year">2016</span>
          <div class="timeline-slide__content">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Our nice super title</h4>
            <p class="timeline-text">Lorem ipsum dolor site amet, consectetur adipscing elit, sed do eisumod tempor incididut ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad mimim venjam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-slide" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1920/600?image=11;" data-year="2017">      <span class="timeline-year">2017</span>
          <div class="timeline-slide__content">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Our first project</h4>
            <p class="timeline-text">First project for the leading film actress Jamuna Barua, wife of Pramathesh Barua the legendary actor, director, and screenwriter</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick.min.js'></script>

  

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si le cambias la altura a timeline-wrapper por no se 1000px se muestra, el tema es que todos te van a quedar con esa altura. Lo que pasa es que cada elemento dentro de timeline-wrapper están como float y por ello no crece el wrapper con la altura de los mismos.

Lee sobre Clearfix y te doy el enlace a un post en el que comentan posibles soluciones.

[métodos clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/what-methods-of-clearfix-can-i-use)

Saludos!